# [ROS2] publishing UInt16

Tags: ros, ros2, std-msgs, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I would like to publish a message without it being of type std_msgs::msg::String.

```
std_msgs::msg::UInt16 statuswoord;

auto publisher = node->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::UInt16>("motor_info", rmw_qos_profile_default);  

auto msg =  std::make_shared<std_msgs::msg::UInt16();

msg->data = statuswoord;
publisher->publish(msg);
```

But I get following error:

> cannot convert ‘std_msgs::msg::UInt16 {aka std_msgs::msg::UInt16_std::allocator<void >}’ to std_msgs::msg::UInt16_std::allocator<void > >::_data_type {aka short unsigned int}’ in assignment
> msg->data = test;

In my case I need it to be UInt16, but it might happen that I need another datatype in the future. Is there a guide somewhere on casting all the std_msgs ?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349003/%5Bros2%5D-publishing-uint16/) by [jlepers](https://answers.ros.org/users/46408/jlepers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2020-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is there a guide somewhere on casting all the std_msgs ?

I don't believe this has anything to do with casting.

There are two issues with the code you show:

```
auto msg =  std::make_shared<std_msgs::msg::UInt16();
```

This line is missing the closing `>` (after `UInt16`), and:

```
std_msgs::msg::UInt16 statuswoord;
msg->data = statuswoord;
```

this can't work.

The field `data` is of type `uint16` in the ROS 2 msg IDL (see [here](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/519e851f6ac71262e45b6e5ca66bce653a72948d/std_msgs/msg/UInt16.msg#L1)), which gets converted to a `std::uint16_t` for C++ (refer to [About ROS 2 interfaces: Message description specification - Fields - Field types](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Concepts/About-ROS-Interfaces/#field-types)), which is a `short unsigned int` on `amd64` and many other architectures.

The `statuswoord` variable is of type `std_msgs::msg::UInt16`.

You cannot assign a `std_msgs::msg::UInt16` to a variable of type `std::uint16_t`.

To make this work, you'll have to change the type of `statuswoord` to `std::uint16_t`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-10**:
Note btw that this is not really a problem specific to ROS 2: in ROS 1 a similar system was used, and publishing a message from the `std_msgs` package, but treating it as a primitive type also didn't work.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-10**:
Note also btw that using the `std_msgs` set of messages is somewhat discouraged. A `short unsigned int` carries almost no semantics, which makes it not very useful for publishing as a ROS message.

You may want to create a new message type, called `StatusWord` and give it a single field (of type `uint16`) called `data` (or something more descriptive). Then publish a `StatusWord` message.

This will make sure that whoever subscribes to your `StatusWord` knows how to deal with those kinds of messages, and it's immediately clear to consumers that they're not receiving just some random `short unsigned int`, but a bitmask encoding the status (of something).